# How to get data from two different tables of linked server

Tags: sql-server, openquery

I am trying to fetch data from a table of linked server using `OPENQUERY` like:

```
SELECT ID, Acronym
 from 
    openquery(LS, 'select * from "SchemaName"."ViewName1" ')
```

Now I need the "full form" values which is in another view "ViewName2" of the linked server. In "ViewName2" Acronym is unique field and "full form" contains values which are full forms of the Acronym values. I have tried to fetch the data using:

```
SELECT ID, Acronym
 from 
    openquery(LS, 'select * from "SchemaName"."ViewName1" ') As A Join
    openquery(LS, 'select * from "SchemaName"."ViewName2" ') AS B On B.Acronym=A.Acronym
```

But It does not work. How to do this?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What is the error you get, or why are the results wrong? Why not perform the `JOIN` inside `OPENQUERY` instead of outside of it? (That'll probably be more performant too.)

Comment: Linked servers are quite easy to use, but also fragile, error-prone, and easy to **abuse**. Here is a clear case of abuse. As Larnu wrote - join in the query that is passed to the linked server. This will avoid pulling the resultsets from both queries into the current db engine only to then join them to generate your desired resultset. Very, very inefficient as written. Now is a good time to get some feedback and assistance from your coworkers - a "team" improves by talking and learning together.

Comment: SELECT ID, Acronym
    FROM OPENQUERY(LS, '
        SELECT ViewName1.* 
        FROM "SchemaName"."ViewName1" AS A
            JOIN "SchemaName"."ViewName2" AS B ON A.Acronym = B.Acronym
    ')